# Why is ( $_SESSION = [];) making the server unable to handle the request?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to clear the variables from a session and start a new one. From reading around about the variable issue, I think I discovered that this is the right answer:

```
( $_SESSION = [];)
```

But when I add that line to my code, on a line by itself within the PHP code, I get a message that "[the server] is currently unable to handle this request," indicating "HTTP ERROR 500."

Without that one command, the page works fine (except that the variables don't behave as I want them to). But every time I activate that line, I get the error. How can I clear the variables without making the server angry?

Update: I have also tried session_destroy(), but it has the same effect. Here is a little more context:

```
<?php 
session_destroy();

session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
session_start();
?>
```

If I comment out the session_destroy() line, the page loads with no trouble. But with that line, I get the error.

Final update for others with this question: I've marked the correct answer. I needed to start the new session before unsetting the variables from the last one.

Comment: share exact code? its not proper in syntax.

Comment: A PHP session can be destroyed by `session_destroy()`

Comment: I thought I had read that session_destroy() is now deprecated. Is it still OK?

Comment: But anyway, the session_destroy() option produces the same problem. I've updated and expanded the code above.

Comment: You are missing ; on session_destroy() line. Anyway, it produces *PHP Warning:  session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session* on several servers I've tried, not HTTP 500. Bottom line. something else is causing it, probably (unless it was the missing semicolon).

Comment: Also, read warning @ php.net manual, it's highlighted in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use session_destroy() before session_start(). Try this:

`session_start();
session_set_cookie_params(3600,"/");
session_destroy();`

Answer (score 0):

To remove all session variables use:

```
session_unset();
```

if you are having issues after destroying your session, then it is likely that your code is trying to access session variables that have not been set.  I like to check with `isset()`
eg

```
$myVar = "";
if (isset($_SESSION('MyVar')) $MyVar = $_SESSION('MyVar');
```